# Trigger change event by changing selectedIndex of select without jQuery

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm changing the `selectedIndex` of select via JS. The problem is that this action doesn't trigger the change or input event. How can I make this work?

```js
let select = document.getElementById("select");
let p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
let count=0;

select.addEventListener("change",function(e){
let divEl = document.getElementById("textidk");
count++;
divEl.innerHTML="selectedIndex has been changed"+count;

  //something happens after I change selectedIndex in js
});
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(e){
 select.selectedIndex=2;
    p.innerHTML=select.selectedOptions[0].innerHTML;
});
```

```html
<p></p>
  <select id="select">
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
    <option value="4">Ford</option>
    <option value="5">Honda</option>
    <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
    <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
    <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="9">Mini</option>
    <option value="10">Nissan</option>
    <option value="11">Toyota</option>
    <option value="12">Volvo</option>
  </select>
<button id="btn">hello</button>
<div id="textidk"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to trigger it manually by just calling `onchange` on your `select` when you are changing the index. Like this:

```
select.onchange();
```

Or you can do:

```
select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

Comment: "select.onchange is not a function" it doesn't work

Comment: Try `select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`

Comment: `select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));`